# javascript: modifing an imported 'variable' causes 'Assignment to constant variable' even it is not a constant

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-module-loader

I have two files, file1 exports a variable 'not a constant' var x=1
and file2 which imports this variable from it

the problem is that I canno't modify that imported variable even it is not a constant!

file1.js

```
export var x=1 //it is defined as a variable not a constant
```

file2.js

```
import {x} from 'file1.js'
console.log(x) //1
x=2 //Error: Assignment to constant variable
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an effect of [the immutable exported module values](http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html#es6-modules-export-immutable-bindings). You can override that with another function in the same module

In your file 1 :

```
export let x = 1;
export function modifyX( value ) { x = value; }
```

In your file 2

```
import { x, modifyX } from "file1.js"

console.log( x ) // 1;
modifyX( 2 );
console.log( x ) // 2;
```

Comment: and yet we can assign properties directly to x. x.foo = 2; works fine, if we have export let x = { foo: 3 }; So the value isn't immutable. Only the binding to the top level value.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set the x as an object property like this:

```
export default {
    x: 1
}
```

then from your second file:

```
import file1API from "./file1.js";

console.log(file1API.x); //1
file1API.x = 2;
console.log(file1API.x); //2
```

note that the value of x will also be updated in "file1.js".