# How can I prevent duplicate import of the same file when there is a GET parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding a module `main.js` to my page with as GET-parameter a random number for it to not be cached on mobile where Ctrl+F5 is more complicated when I'm developping.

```html
<script type="module" src="main.js?t=12341234"></script>
```

Now in this file I have a variable `userIsTyping` and an event listener that calls `makeAjaxCall` from `ajax.js` on input.

```js
import {makeAjaxCall} from "./ajax.js";

export let userIsTyping = false;
// A function has to be created to modify the value from another module https://stackoverflow.com/a/53723394/9013718
export function changeUserIsTyping(value) {
    userIsTyping = value;
}

let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
let textareaInputPauseTimeoutId;
textarea.addEventListener('input', function () {
    // Set var to true as soon as there is a user input
    userIsTyping = true;
    clearTimeout(textareaInputPauseTimeoutId);
    textareaInputPauseTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // Runs 1 second after the last change
        makeAjaxCall.call(textarea);
    }, 1000);
});
```

The second module is making the ajax call and the key here is that between the time where the ajax request is started and its response callback, I need to be able to know if `userIsTyping` became `true` in the meantime.

```js
import {changeUserIsTyping, userIsTyping} from "./main.js";

export function makeAjaxCall() {
    changeUserIsTyping(false);
    // Make ajax call
    let xHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (userIsTyping === false) {
                // If user typed something between the beginning of the request and now it wouldn't reach here.
            } else {
                // User typed something in the meantime
            }
        }
    };
    xHttp.open('PUT', 'notes/' + this.dataset.noteId, true);
    xHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xHttp.send(JSON.stringify({[this.name]: this.value}));

}
```

This does kind of work but the ajax call is always called twice. I found that the reason could be that the browser loads `main.js?t=12341234` that has an event listener on input that calls the `makeAjaxCall` and there is also a `main.js` (which is the same file but without the GET parameter.

Is there a way to make the browser know that they have identical contents and should not be fully loaded and executed both?

A quick fix would be to put the input event listener into the `ajax.js` so that it doesn't have to import `main.js` but there are other occurences where I seem to be blocked between importing modules and wanting to add a GET param so that there is no cache on mobile.
But I showed the full context of what I'm trying to do in case anyone has a better idea to do this, I'd love suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the issue I put the logic that was in `main.js` to another file that was imported via module import and then had the same code between those files.

But I still don't have an answer to my question: is it possible to import a module that was also loaded by html `<script>` but with a GET-param and not have both run their code at the same time?